# SwiftUI - How to toogle all the booleans in a CoreData

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I have a database with several objects with booleans as attribute. I'm looking for a function to invert all boolean objects when I press a button. I tried this function but several errors are displayed like (Value of type 'Bool' has no member 'indices') :

```
struct ViewList: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
  @State var newName: String = ""
  @FetchRequest(
      entity: Product.entity(),
      sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Product.name, ascending: true)]
  ) var list: FetchedResults<Product>

  var body: some View {
      VStack {
          HStack {
                TextField("I insert the name of the product", text: $newName)
              Button(action: { self.add()
                               self.newName = ""
              })
              { Image(systemName: "plus") }
          }
          List {
              ForEach(list, id: \.self) {
                  product in ViewItem(product: product)
              }
          }
      }
  }
  public func add() {
      let newProduct = Product(context: context)
      newProduct.name = newName
      do {
          try context.save()
      } catch {
          print(error)
      }
  }
}                       


struct ViewItem: View {
  @State var product: Product
  @State var refresh: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
      NavigationLink(destination: ViewDetail(product: product, refresh: $refresh)) {
          HStack(alignment: .top) {
              Button( action: {
                  self.clean()
                  self.product.isSelected.toggle()
              }) {
                  if self.product.isSelected == true {
                      Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                  } else {
                      Image(systemName: "checkmark").colorInvert()
                  }
              }
              VStack() {
                  Text(product.name)
                  if product.password != "" {
                      Text("Password : " + product.password)
                  }
                  Text(String(refresh)).hidden()
              }
          }
      }
      .onAppear {
          self.refresh = false
      }
  }
```

}

I've been thinking about it, but I don't know how to go about it...

```
func clean() {
    for( index ) in self.product.isSelected.indices {
        self.product[index]isSelected = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Your var product is a single instance of Product. It looks like the var list which is the output of the FetchRequest is the thing you should be iterating over.

Comment: @WarrenBurton :  I want to put the function in the struct ViewItem, how can I retrieve the database "list" when I'm in the struct VeiwItem ?

Comment: You want to flip the selected state of all products in list ? Or just the one product in ViewItem?

Comment: I get it , you have a tableview and when you select an item you want to deselect the previous selection. Storing the selection (view) state in your data (model) isn’t a great design choice. A possible pattern is create a selection handler class that remembers the selection state , pass that object to ViewItem and use that to change the selection. Have a look at the selection mechanics in https://www.raywenderlich.com/7705231-creating-a-mind-map-ui-in-swiftui and I’ll try and answer the question tomorrow

Comment: @WarrenBurton: Thank you for the link, I will study this. I have put the boolean isSelected into the entity product, since I want to store it in Coredata and refind the selected product next time I start the application. Thus, when the ViewDetail is displayed for a product, the former selected product must be unselected in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a query to flip the state of the `isSelected` flag. This logic is best kept out of the view system so you can use it anywhere.

You create a `SelectionHandler`

```
import CoreData

class SelectionHandler {

    func clearSelection(in context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        for item in currentSelected(in: context) {
            item.isSelected = false
        }
    }

    func selectProduct(_ product: Product) {
        guard let context = product.managedObjectContext else {
            assertionFailure("broken !")
            return
        }

        clearSelection(in: context)
        product.isSelected = true
    }

    func currentSelected(in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [Product] {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Product>(entityName: Product.entity().name!)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isSelected == YES")
        request.predicate = predicate

        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            return result
        } catch  {
            print("fetch error =",error)
            return []
        }

    }

}
```

which you can then use to select your desired product.

`SelectionHandler().selectProduct(product)`

As it stands your `NavigationLink` will do nothing because the parent list is not held in a `NavigationView` so you'll need to change the body of `ViewList` to look like this.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("Create product with name", text: $newName)
                Button(action: {
                    self.add()
                    self.newName = ""
                })
                { Image(systemName: "plus") }
            }
            .padding()
            List {
                ForEach(list, id: \.self) { product in
                    ViewItem(product: product)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in `ViewItem` , `Product` should be an `ObservedObject` so that changes are detected in the managedObject.

```
struct ViewItem: View {

    @ObservedObject var product: Product
    @State var refresh: Bool = false

    var checkmarkImage: some View {
        return Group {
            if self.product.isSelected {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark").colorInvert()
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ViewDetail(product: product, refresh: $refresh)) {
            HStack {
                checkmarkImage
                Text(product.name ?? "wat")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The original `Button` won't play with the `NavigationLink` but you can simply apply the selection to `onAppear` in `ViewDetail`

```
struct ViewDetail: View {

    @ObservedObject var product: Product
    @Binding var refresh: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
            Text("Product is \(product.name ?? "wat")")
        }
        .onAppear {
            SelectionHandler().selectProduct(self.product)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Exactly what I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: @Warren hi, thanks for this! I dont use:
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context

- how can i make this work with : 
let container: NSPersistentContainer

Comment: You use the `NSManagedObjectContext` supplied by the container `persistentContainer.viewContext`  . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer